# Access Chrome History through JDBC

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, google-chrome, locking, readonly

I'm trying to connect to the chrome history database (sqlite) via a java application and run some queries in read only mode. I'm using sqlite.jar but when I connect, I get the following error:
org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.SqlJetException: BUSY: error code is BUSY
I know some applications can access the file without copying it first (like wxSQLitePlus) or making sure the browser is not using the file, how do they do it?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Since the "history" file is being used by Chrome (assuming Chrome was running when you got the BUSY error), Chrome currently holds a "EXCLUSIVE" lock on the file. During this, no other application can access the same file. Even for read-only process.